# Rspec View Testing for form_for

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, form-for, automated-tests

I am having a view file _edit.html.erb

```
 <%= form_for(@search_phrase, remote: true) do |f| %>
   <h4> Keyword </h4>
   <%= f.text_field :keyword %><br/>
   <%= f.submit "Add", class: "btn btn-medium btn-primary" %>
   <%= render 'error' %>
 <% end %>
```

I am writing view rspec tests for it/ My test goes like this in _edit.html.erb_spec.rb

```
describe "search_phrases/_edit.html.erb" do
  include Devise::TestHelpers
  User.destroy_all

  before :all do
    @user = User.find_by_name('testuser')
    @user ||= begin
    user = User.new(email: "test@gmail.com",
    encrypted_password: "$2a$10$TIJrH0tmQ7VuDeBVBIYhJ......................",
    provider: "facebook", uid: "10000697585", name: "testuser",
    fb_token: "AUExuiUkFoBAEsYdxTfU1ONYanI55Sx5ThBTjo7qnKLiZ")
    user.save!
    user
  end
end

before  :each do
  User.stub(:find_for_facebook_oauth).and_return(@user)
  sign_in @user
end

before :all do
  @search_phrase = SearchPhrase.find_by_user_id(@user.id)
  @search_phrase ||= begin
    search_phrase= SearchPhrase.new(keyword: "testkeyword",user_id: @user.id) #never hard code
    search_phrase.save!
    search_phrase
  end
end

it "creates a form" do
    render
    rendered.should_receive(:form_for).with edit_search_phrase_path(@search_phrase)   
  end
end
```

But the test fails giving an error

```
search_phrases/_edit.html.erb creates a form
     Failure/Error: render
     ActionView::Template::Error:
       undefined local variable or method `search_phrase' for #<#<Class:0x000000073080c0>:0x00000007371b38>
     # ./app/views/search_phrases/_edit.html.erb:1:in `_app_views_search_phrases__edit_html_erb__4315365547541336689_61378180'
     # ./spec/views/search_phrases/_edit.html.erb_spec.rb:45:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 0.30383 seconds
1 example, 1 failure

Failed examples:

rspec ./spec/views/search_phrases/_edit.html.erb_spec.rb:44 # search_phrases/_edit.html.erb creates a form
```

What is creating problem here, I am unable to figure out that.

Answer (score 0):

You may have missed the routes

```
#in routes.rb
 resources :search_phrases
 ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to add
`assign(:search_phrase, @search_phrase)`
in the `before :all` block. i.e.

```
before :all do
  @search_phrase = SearchPhrase.find_by_user_id(@user.id)
  @search_phrase ||= begin
   search_phrase= SearchPhrase.new(keyword: "testkeyword",user_id: @user.id) #never hard code
   search_phrase.save!
   search_phrase
  end
  assign(:search_phrase, @search_phrase
end
```

https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/v/3-3/docs/view-specs/view-spec